# Tkinter / Python Combobox options should change the event of the Start button

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, tkinter-button

I'm using a ComboBox as part of a GUI, written in python/tkinter.

When the drop-down selection is changed, the Start Button should start another file. for example: I have an Start button and a ComboBox and in their are 2 options, July and September and if I choose September the Start button should open up another file then July, September.py and July.py how can I do that?

```
button1 = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text="Start",
    style="Accentbutton")
button1.place(x=25, y=30)

course=["September", "July"]
l1=Label(root, text="Month")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)
cmb=ttk.Combobox(root, state="readonly", value=course,width=10)
cmb.grid(row=1,column=0)
cmb.current(0)
cmb.place(x=25, y=230)
l1.place(x=25, y=210)
```

Comment: Including code, better known as [mre] will higher your chances to get an answer. Please consider to take the [tour] and to take a look at [ask] to [edit] your question before it gets closed.

Comment: Okay thank u its better now?

Comment: slightly, yes. We want to be able to copy and paste your code to reproduce your issue. Why should we put in the effort to write the code to reproduce your problem? In addition, it does happen quite often that I finish that code and it works, because the issue is not in the shared snippet but in the code that I've added and fixed it without knowing what the issue was. So please take another [edit] to your question.

Comment: Idk what i should add to that its the Start Button and the Code from my Combobox does the rest of the code really matter? bc it has nothing to do with the combo and the button

Comment: I would need to add a window and a function that simulates your attempt to open the file. Where and how do you call it? What does open a file mean in your case ? You want to run a script or open it as a window or read data from the file? I don't see how I should address your question, it needs more details. What do you actual need help with ?

Comment: as a general answer for your question, have the logic that is executed when the start button is pressed check what the selection of your combobox contains and have it act accordingly...

Comment: I am a very beginner sry i cant tell you much i just want that if you choose option 1 that it opens version1.py when you press start for example.  same for version 2 and 3. just that it executes an python project if you know what i mean